# non-monomial group with a strong property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

The groups are finite and representations are over $\mathbb{C}$.

A group $G$ is said to be monomial if any irreducible representation of $G$ of dimension $>1$ is induced from one-dimensional representation of some subgroup.

Of course, there are non-monomial groups. But among them, I want to consider examples of groups with further property:

> **Q.** Are there non-monomial groups, whose any irreducible representation of dimension $>1$ is not induced from irreducible representation of any subgroup?
>
> Writing this symbolically, is there a finite group $G$ with $\chi\in$ Irr$(G)$ such that
>
> (1) $\chi(1)>1$.
>
> (2) There is *no* pair $(H,\psi)$ with $H$ proper subgroup of $G$, $\psi\in $Irr$(H)$ and $\chi=\mbox{Ind}_H^G \psi$

Comment: $A_5$ should be an example: There are irreducible characters of degree 3, but $A_5$ has no proper subgroup of index dividing 3, so they cannot be induced.

Comment: Would the 5-dimensional irreducible reps of $G=S_5$ serve in the role $\chi$? Because $5$ is a prime we need $H$ to have index five, so essentially $H=S_4$, and $\psi$ is 1-dimensional. But IIRC the characters we get from inducing a linear character of $S_4$ to $S_5$ are not irreducible.

Comment: @Dune: Would you mind fleshing that out to an answer? It may be the smallest example?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I just guessed the group, and looked up the facts in tables. But if I find some time I will think about smaller examples.

Comment: FWIW I posted my example as an answer to [your other recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2071169/11619).

Comment: One might also ask for the stronger condition that no irrep is induced from a proper subgroup. Or for that matter the "reverse" that all non-linear irreps are induced from some proper subgroup. Or for that matter an in between where they are induced from a character of at most some degree (fixed or depending on something). These are all potentially interesting questions, though I have no idea if any of them lead anywhere.

Comment: For another possible generalization of M-groups you might be interested in my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1383 which should be fairly easy to read given your current knowledge (though it might of course turn out to be a dead end).

Comment: I haven't found a nonabelian example in which no irreducible representation is induced from a proper subgroup, so it might be an interesting question whether such an example exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [list of small groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups) we see that all groups up to order 23 are monomial (all but the alternating group $A_4$ are even supersolvable). There is a unique non-monomial group of order 24, namely $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$. This group has irreducible characters of degree two (see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_special_linear_group:SL%282,3%29)), but none of them are induced by smaller ones, since there is no subgroup of index two in $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$. So this is the smallest example of a group you are looking for.